# Postgres earthdistance 'function point(text, text) does not exist' error

Tags: postgresql, earthdistance

I am new to Postgres geo queries, I want to find locations within a 10km radius of a particular point so I came across earthdistance. I installed the extension using `CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance;`

After that, I ran my query

```
SELECT *, (point(lng, lat) <@> point(-0.1281552,51.5107975)) AS distance FROM location WHERE (point(lng, lat) <@> point(-0.1281552,51.5107975)) < 10000 ORDER BY distance;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  function point(text, text) does not exist
LINE 1: select *, point(lng, lat) <@> point(-0.1281552,51.5107975) a...
                  ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I did some search but was not able to find any solution.

Comment: What's the data type of lat and lng? Describe your table location

Comment: `point` takes numbers as its arguments, not strings

Comment: The data type for both is text. Thanks

Comment: "You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: Yeah as @Bergi said `point` does not takes a strings as an argumenst so I typecasted it and the error was gone.